# What is the difference between informed and uninformed searches?

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence

What is the difference between informed and uninformed searches? Can you explain this with some examples?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Blind or Uniformed Search

It is a search without "information" about the goal node.

An example an is breadth-first search (BFS). In BFS, the search proceeds one layer after the other. In other words, nodes in the same layer are first visited before nodes in successive layers. This is performed until a node that is "expanded" is the goal node. In this case, no information about the goal node is used to visit, expand or generate nodes.

We can think of a blind or uniformed search as a brute-force search.

#### Heuristic or Informed Search

It is a search with "information" about the goal.

An example of such type of algorithm is A*. In this algorithm, nodes are visited and expanded using also information about the goal node. The information about the goal node is given by an **heuristic function** (which is a function that associates information about the goal node to each of the nodes of the state space). In the case of A*, the heuristic information associated with each node `n` is an estimate of the distance from `n` to the goal node.

We can think of a informed search as a approximately "guided" search.

Answer (score 5):

An **uninformed search** is a brute-force or "blind" search. It uses no knowledge about problem, hence possibly less efficient than an informed search.

Examples of uninformed search algorithms are breadth-first search, depth-first search, depth-limited search, uniform-cost search, depth-first iterative deepening search and bidirectional search.

An **informed search** (also called "heuristic search") uses prior knowledge about problem ("domain knowledge"), hence possibly more efficient than uninformed search.

Examples of informed search algorithms are best-first search and A*.

Answer (score -1):

Difference between uniformed search and informed search are given below :

1. Uniformed search technique have access only to the problem definition 
   whereas Informed search technique have access to the heuristic function  and 
   problem definition.
2. Uniformed search is less efficient whereas informed search is more efficient.
3. Uniformed search known as blind search whereas Informed search is known as heuristic search.
4. Uniformed search use more computation whereas Informed search use less computation.

Comment: More efficient or inefficient in terms of what? Any proof of this claim?